# Specific Column permission in Microsoft lists

Tags: project-planning

I have query where I want a specific column in my Microsoft List to be uneditable to all users except for a specific user group or specific users.

Is it possible to put to place such restrictions on a specific column in my List?

We have a team site that we'd like to open up to an external supplier, but we would like them to modify only certain columns, to read others and to hide others.